# Do threads/processes have to disable interrupts while executing a critical section

Tags: locking, interrupt, critical-section, interrupt-handling

Let us consider a scenario:-

A Kernel thread acquires a lock and is in the middle of a critical section when an interrupt occurs.
The interrupt handler runs and arrives at the same critical section and tries to acquire lock and go to sleep.

Can this happen or are interrupts disabled during a critical section ?
what steps are taken to to avoid it ?

```
// Some Code
 Acquire_lock()

Critical section   //Interrupt occurs and arrives to acquire the same lock.

Disable_lock()
```

Comment: Do you have particular platform in mind or is this just a generic question?

Comment: A generic question. Let's say Linux kernel on x86 machine ?

Answer (score 2):

You would never allow code that holds a lock to be interrupted by code that attempts to acquire that same lock. If you mean inside the OS, it may require disabling all interrupts in code that interacts with objects that are also manipulated by interrupt handlers.

User-space threads and processes have no such issue. No interrupt handler acquires a lock that user-space threads can acquire. And if a thread that holds a user-space lock is interrupted, it will release it as soon as it gets rescheduled -- the user-space thread is still ready-to-run.

Comment: Sorry, I did not mention I was talking about Kernel threads.
So basically kernel threads _MUST and SHOULD_ disable interrupts before entering a critical section ?
How does it decide which interrupt line should be disabled ? Or does it disable all interrupts in general ?

Comment: If they're going to hold a lock that an interrupt handler might try to acquire, they need to at least disabling servicing of that interrupt on that core.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz What if the interrupt which the processor would get during the critical section execution can't be missed? How this situation can be handled?

Comment: @XavierGeoffrey It's not missed. The hardware just defers it. If your question is "what happens if an interrupt must be serviced at a time when it cannot be serviced", well, any system that had a time at which an interrupt both had to be serviced and could not be serviced would be broken.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Yes, that's exactly I was asking. And I couldn't understand the meaning of "broken" here exactly. Does that mean this scenario can not be handled ever? For me, this looks like a legitimate scenario in a Real Time world...

Comment: @XavierGeoffrey A system is "broken" if its design creates conflicting requirements. A system whose design had a state in which an interrupt both had to be processed and could not be processed would be broken. The design would have to be changed. Avoiding this problem is one of the reasons interrupt processing is split into pieces with the piece requiring interrupts to be disabled being as small as possible.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz thanks for the explanation. With Linux's top and bottom half interrupt approach, this scenario can be handled?

Comment: @XavierGeoffrey Exactly. The portion of the handler where any interrupts have to be disabled is kept as small as possible.